# Display the list by using server side processing and pagenumber

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Goal:
When you press one of the pagenumber, the data should be sent to the url "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=" together witha number.
You press pagenumber 2, the url will be "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=2" and then you retrieve the data.

The dipslay list should always show 4 row in the table, if the list is more than 4 row, please use pagenumber.

Problem:
I tried to solve it but it doesn't go so well. What part of the code am I missing?

Jsbin:
jsbin.com/dabusuhuku/edit?html.js,console.output

Thank you!

---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div class="container">
  <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>


<br/>

<br/>

<br/>
<br/>
```

---

```
var pagenumber = 1;

$('#example').DataTable( {
    
  "processing": true, 
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax":{
    url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=" + pagenumber,
    dataSrc: ""
  },

  "columns": [
    { data: "postId" },
    { data: "id" },
    { data: "name" },
    { data: "email" },
    { data: "body" }
  ]
    
});



var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
  console.log(table.page());
  pagenumber = table.page() + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **?postId=N** is a filter criterion to get all the comments related to a specific post number, not a page.
If you want to get the real paged data across the whole comments dataset, you need to provide the **_page=N** and **_limit=N1**.

So in your scenario, the first page with 4 comments will look like this:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?_page=1&_limit=4

Then you need to exchange the page number with the desired one.

Secondly, when you set something in the **ajax.url** property, it's always a static value (one-time set), even if you provide a concatenated value as you did:

url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=" + pagenumber

It means that the url string value will be composed with the first part and the pagenumber value one time at the beginning (so changes to the pagenumber won't be reflected).

Thirdly, the dataTables can work in two modes: client and serverside, if you choose the serverside, your server must support the query parameters that dataTables are using to filter out data:

- draw
- start
- length
- search
- columns

The jsonplaceholder has it's own API syntax described here: https://github.com/typicode/json-server

So if you really want to use this API endpoint, you have to create your own adapter middleware which will translate the request/response from the syntax that is used by the dataTable to the one that can be understood by the jsonplaceholder.

Comment: In this context, I will be using .Net core as a backend in relation to web api

Comment: Should I use Server-side processing or client side for this datatables?

Comment: The recommendation is to use client-side processing in case you have dataset with <50k records

Comment: If you have more than 50k records to show, you can think about some more sophisticated implementation with caching described here: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

Comment: What I need to is to send pagenumber, selected column, selected columns sort order from frontend to backend.

The backend will provide the new information, based on parameter,  from the database.

Can this be applied both to client and serverside?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it. If you want to use a clientside, you can do it right away just by removing server processing options and query parameters from the endpoint url (just tested it, and works like a charm). If you want to use serverside, better to check with request is getting triggered by your app, and there you'll see al the query parameters sent out.

Comment: @What'sUP If this answer helps you, please mark it as accepted by the author.

Comment: Sorry for my delay